# Convert time to character in R

Tags: r, time

I read a dataframe `dtmn` from a csv file with the following time value.

In Excel it shows:
`7/4/2014 13:08`

When I read it in R it shows:

```
> x <- dtmn[2,1]
> x
[1] 7/4/2014
Levels: 0.547222222 7/4/2014 7/4/2014 13:08 788
```

I would like to convert this into a character form, with the following character values:

```
"07/04/2014 13:08"
```

The function `as.character.Posixt(dtmn[2,1])` returns date only : `[1] "7/4/2014"`
But I am trying to include the time also. So the desired output may look like this:
`"07/04/2014 13:08"`

Please help,

Comment: I think you have to ask yourself how you came to have this messy data in the first place.  I would backtrack and try to fix that problem, then converting to a date-time will be much easier.

Comment: the data frame `dtmn` came from an excel csv file, I read it in R. 
In excel it just looks like this "7/4/2014  1:08:00 PM". I think that R did something to it, and interpreted it in some way which I don't understand. But for my purpose, I just need it as a character value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to solve this is using the `readxl` package. Suppose you have an excel file named `excel_file.xlsx`, and your data column is formatted as date in Excel:

```
date_from_excel
07/04/14 13:08
07/04/14 21:30
07/12/14 10:18

library(readxl)

df = read_excel(path=paste0("/<path-to-the-file>/",'excel_file.xlsx'), sheet=1, col_names=T, col_types=c('date') )
df = as.data.frame(df)
df$date_as_string = as.character(df$date_from_excel)

> df
  date_from_excel      date_as_string
1 2014-04-07 13:08:00 2014-04-07 13:08:00
2 2014-04-07 21:30:00 2014-04-07 21:30:00
3 2014-12-07 10:18:00 2014-12-07 10:18:00

> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date_from_excel: POSIXct, format: "2014-04-07 13:08:00" "2014-04-07 21:30:00" ...
 $ date_as_string : chr  "2014-04-07 13:08:00" "2014-04-07 21:30:00" "2014-12-07 10:18:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rich Scriven's comment helped me understand this. I checked the class and levels.

```
> class(dtmn[2,1])
[1] "factor"
> levels(dtmn[2,1])
[1] "0.547222222"    "7/4/2014"       "7/4/2014 13:08" "788"
```

Finally, calling the third level as character:

```
> as.character(levels(dtmn[2,1])[3])
[1] "7/4/2014 13:08"
```